# File, Edit, Options, etc. menus don't work on Emacs 23, any ideas?

Tags: emacs

I upgraded to Emacs 23 a while back and when I did the File, Edit, Options, and other menu options are not available on OS X Snow Leopard. Any ideas how to get them back?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I need to make it more clear what is happening. I can see the labels for File, Edit, Options, Tools, Minibuf, YASSnippet, etc. that appear where all native OS X apps show their menus, but clicking on them no longer yields a drop down menu. Very strange.

Comment: Editing the question is a good way to add additional information and precisions ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Just a note*** that you can access the menus in emacs by `menu-bar-open` <kbd>F10</kbd> by default. This allows you to navigate the menu even when you have opened emacs in no-window mode (`-nw` command line switch).

`menu-bar-open` will attempt to open the menu depending on the frame's terminal device. If all else fails it will open the text mode menu `tmm-menubar`.

You could try <kbd>F10</kbd> to see if the native menu appears. If nothing happens you could make an interactive call to `tmm-menubar` like so: <kbd>M-x</kbd>`tmm-menubar`. Does the text menu work?

Even if this does not solve your problem it is useful knowledge to help you navigate the menu when you haven't got a visible frame.

Comment: Ok, now you are on to something. I can get the textual menu which is actually very cool. Thanks a lot for that tip. I still want them back in the native OS X menu location, but this will work until I find the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had problem with the menu bar (in GUI mode), such that certain menus weren't showing - like `yasnippet`, `python` and `elpy`. Pressing `f10` showed them in a strange way, but then the regular way worked again after hitting `f10` a second time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I hit this problem and found the following root cause.  I don't have a fix yet but thought I'd post to see if this matches the original poster's issue.

I am using Synergy to share a keyboard and mouse across multiple side-by-side machines.  My Macbook is running OS X 10.6.3, and is a Synergy "client".
Using the shared mouse, the Emacs 23.3 menus do not work; however, using the touchpad on the Macbook, the menus *do* work.
I'm using Synergy v1.3.1 on the Mac.

The only work-around I've found is to use either the Macbook touchpad or a mouse connected directly to the Macbook.

Comment: Thanks for your input Tad. This wasn't my situation. I ended up switching back to Carbon Emacs for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Wild! This was my issue; thanks for suggesting it.  See the bug report at Synergy's site here: http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/332. Note that this bug seems to occur in VNC and Apple Remote Desktop, too.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you used "carbon-emacs" as a tag leads me to believe you probably do not have the Cocoa version, which is highly recommended to the point of being the standard GNU Emacs for the Mac going forward.  Check [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/) for a .dmg package.

Comment: pajato0, that is actually where I got my emacs from, but thank you! It looks exactly like carbon emacs, so I thought it was.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same problem with the build installed from macports.  I don't know why it happens.  However, what worked for me was clicking on the menu a few times.  After I did this, I was able to hover over and click the menu items properly.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been occurring from time to time on my Emacs v23 on OS X installed via Homebrew. The solution posted by nomad worked for me:

> However, what worked for me was clicking on the menu a few times. After I did this, I was able to hover over and click the menu items properly.

It seems to be appearing after I open a Python file. The problem keeps coming back though. Every time, tripple-clicking a menu, rapidly, opens the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `M-x menu-bar-mode`. If that works, make sure that you don't disable the menu bar in your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://lists.aquamacs.org/pipermail/aquamacs-bugs/2010-April/003909.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I switched to Carbon Emacs, no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when access Emacs (the one prepared by Vincent Goulet) through TeamViewer on a remote machine. The menus did not drop down. After the user directly at the machine did it once, I could also use the menus through the mouse on my remote machine.

Comment: After the user did *what* once ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you are using a Wacom tablet. I have the same issue, and Magnus's response about multiple-clicking reminded me of a problem I had with Wacom and iTunes:

http://accretiondisc.com/blog/2011/07/23/itunes-playlists-dragndrop-and-wacom-tablets/

Sure enough, when I plugged in a mouse and tried the emacs menus, they worked fine.